# Get Max 3 values from Map

Tags: apex, map

Suppose my Map is A->1, B->2, C->3, D->3, E->4, F-4, G->5

My output should be G, F and E

```
declare ur map as above say 

map1 list<Integer> lst =map1.values(); 
lst.sort(); 
Integer lastRank = lst[lst.size()-1]; 
String ss = ''; 
integer counter = 0 ; 
While(counter < 3){ 
  for(String name : map1.keySet()){ 
    if(map1.get(name) >= lastRank){ 
      if(counter<3){ 
        ss = ss + name + ', '; 
        counter ++ ; 
      } 
    } 
 } lastRank --; 
} 
System.debug(ss);
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Hi gaurav, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). This site isn't a code-writing service, it's much more about overcoming specific problems, and growing as a programmer. If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm), the `Map` class contains a method called `values()`.

This method returns a list of the values contained in the map.

Also, as you can see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm%23apex_methods_system_list), the `List` class contains a method called `sort()`.

This method sort the values in the list in ascending order.

So, if you apply the sort method on the values of your map, you will have the 3 bigger values on the end of the list. Of course, don't forget to check that this list contains at least 3 values.

Comment: You'll probably have to clone the list to sort it. Not certain but I think so.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I just checked. It's working by declaring a new List set to the map values. Of course, it's not working by trying to sort directly on the values.

Comment: @AdrianLarson By testing, I just found out that apparently the map sorts the keys in order ascending (tested with integers and characters). But I couldn't find any mention in the documentation.

Comment: Dear All, Sorting list is easy but I need the three biggest key not value.. I figured it out.. this is what I tried that worked (not best but working)

Comment: Not able to post code, it allows limited text..

Comment: declare ur map as above say map1
list<Integer> lst =map1.values();
lst.sort();
Integer lastRank = lst[lst.size()-1];
String ss = '';
        integer        counter = 0 ;
                While(counter < 3){
                  for(String name : map1.keySet()){
                     if(map1.get(name) >= lastRank){
                      if(counter<3){
                       ss = ss + name + ', ';
                       counter ++ ;
                     }
                   }
                  }
                  lastRank --;
                }
System.debug(ss);